# Add multiple 12 column rows in one Bootstrap row class using empty columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add multiple 12 column rows in one Bootstrap row class. But by using empty columns (I call them cells) then this does not work.

Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <!-- no text -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        First row with this entry
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <!-- no text -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <!-- no text -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        Second row with this entry
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <!-- no text -->
    </div>
</div>
```

But i do not to use e.g.   like here:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    &nbsp;<!-- no text -->
</div>
```

Comment: Use [`offset`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting), and you should wrap your divs in a `.col-md-12`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `col-md-offset-1` for the leftmost columns...

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          First row with this entry
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
          <!-- no text -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          Second row with this entry
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
          <!-- no text -->
      </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/uwoYHesTg7

Comment: Using only <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
               First row with this entry
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
               Second row with this entry
           </div>
     </div> is the same output. Why?

Comment: I do not understand col-md-offset-1

Comment: What don't you understand? Offset simply "pushes" the column 1 unit to the right.

Comment: OK, but why are <div class="col-md-1">
          <!-- no text -->
      </div> necessary here? Why do they not work using before an entry with text?

Comment: They're not necessary. I thought your question was how to avoid using `<div class="col-md-1">
    &nbsp;<!-- no text -->
</div>`

Comment: Yes, particularly &nbsp; in one "cell".

Comment: With "offset" I have another problem: if I add another column near the col with offset a second offset is generated in between of the two columns (columns look like this: offset - col with content - offset - col with content). The second offset intefers.